# Book a return flight a year in advance

Tags: usa, airlines, bookings, south-africa, around-the-world

Is it possible to buy an airline ticket that has me returning to my country after a year being abroad? I can't seem to book a flight that far in advance online.

Comment: also see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-is-the-best-method-of-purchasing-a-ticket-with-an-open-return-date

Answer (score 10):

Most airlines allow you to book up to *exactly* 12 months in advance.

This means you can buy a ticket where your outbound flight is today and your return (inbound) flight is exactly one year from today.  Any other dates would be outside of this range. i.e. even an outbound flight tomorrow with an inbound flight of one year from tomorrow would be more than 12 months in advance.

One option you could try is to book a flexi-date fare that allows you to change the date of your flights with minimal charge.

Comment: (+1) Regarding the last option, you really need to read the fine print, I believe that even flexible tickets with no change fees typically do not allow you to go over the 12-month limit, starting from your original booking date.

Comment: Yes, the idea is you book a return flight with a return date of one year from now and then say 6 months from now you change the return date to your desired date